# Mocha Unit Test for TypeScript in VS2015

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, mocha.js

I am using empty node.js typescript project.
When I add the Mocha Unit Test for type script, it shows me that it can't find some keywords ("describe", "it") as follows:
[image]

How should I resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to add a d.ts file for Mocha so that the TypeScript compiler understands the library you're consuming. There are several ways to get this file:

1. Go to http://definitelytyped.org/ and browse the GitHub repo for Mocha. It looks like you can find the one you want here: https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/ffceea9dd124d277c4597c7bd12930666ec074c5/mocha/mocha-node.d.ts
2. Use tsd from the command line (http://definitelytyped.org/tsd/). This is an npm package that installs d.ts files from DefinitelyTyped. After installing, browse to the root directory you want to add the file to and run `tsd install mocha-node` from the command line.
3. Use Nuget to find the Mocha d.ts file. First, click here:[image] then search for mocha and install this package:[image].

After you've grabbed the d.ts file, you need to add a /// <reference> tag to your unit test so that Visual Studio finds the d.ts file and can parse it. Something like this - /// <reference path="typings/mocha/mocha.d.ts"/>.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I ran npm i -D @types/mocha @types/expect then made referense in test.ts file: /// <reference path="./node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts" />  Never understood why not VS fixed this for me.

Answer (score 2):

As @Michael Braude said[@Michael Braude said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33453798/5440633), import mocha's `d.ts` file,
now we can simply do this;

1. Install mocha and mocha type define by

   ```
   npm i -D mocha @types/mocha
   ```
2. Add this line in your `*.test.ts` file

   ```
   import 'mocha'
   ```

Comment: Installing the @types/mocha package solved it for me without importing "mocha". Thank you!